# Typescript 'this' scope issue

Tags: angular, typescript

When I call the findFromList function from a component, this error gets triggered:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchInArray' of undefined
>       at push../src/app/shared/services/filter.service.ts.FilterService.searchInObject
>   (filter.service.ts:40)

This seems to be because 'this' doesn't refer to FilterService anymore in the searchInObject function.

Angular FilterService code:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FilterService {


  findFromList(list, keyword) {
    return list.filter((el) => this.search(el, keyword));
  }

  search(el, keyword) {
    const type = Array.isArray(el) ? 'array' : typeof el;
    const searchFunc = this.getFuncByType(type);

    return searchFunc(el, keyword);
  }

  getFuncByType(type) {

    const match = {
      'string': this.searchInText,
      'number': this.searchInText,
      'boolean': this.searchInText,
      'array': this.searchInArray,
      'object': this.searchInObject,
    };

    if (typeof match[type] !== 'undefined') {
      return match[type];
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unknown element type "${type}"`);
    }
  }

  searchInText(text, keyword) {
    return (text.toString().indexOf(keyword) !== -1);
  }

  searchInObject(obj, keyword) {
    return this.searchInArray(Object.values(obj), keyword);
  }

  searchInArray(arr, keyword) {
    return arr.find((el) => this.search(el, keyword)) !== undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you inject the service and how did you call the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is be cause of the object you define in `getFuncByType`. It causes the `this` to refer to that object and not the `FilterService` class. Update the definition to be:

```js
const match = {
  'string': this.searchInText.bind(this),
  'number': this.searchInText.bind(this),
  'boolean': this.searchInText.bind(this),
  'array': this.searchInArray.bind(this),
  'object': this.searchInObject.bind(this),
};
```

By binding each function to `this` it will keep the context of the function as the class' context.